# Using Javascript to Filter Functions Outputs for only as long as they are true (Javascript Algorithm)

Tags: javascript, algorithm, function

**Question**

Given the array arr, iterate through and remove each element starting from the first element (the 0 index) until the function func returns true when the iterated element is passed through it.

Then return the rest of the array once the condition is satisfied, otherwise, arr should be returned as an empty array.

**This is What I Tried**

```js
function dropElements(arr, func) {
  let filteredArray = arr.filter((item) => {
    return func(arr[item]) == true;
  })

  if (filteredArray == true) {
    return filteredArray;
  } else {
    return [];
  }
}

console.log(dropElements([1, 2, 3, 4], function(n) {
  return n > 5;
}));

console.log(dropElements([1, 2, 3, 4], function(n) {
  return n >= 3;
}))
```

Comment: I am still confuse about your problem. Can you please explain little bit bit more like what you are trying to achieve or expected output etc..

Comment: There is a *Tidy* button below the save snippet button to format the code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to use `filter`, set a flag which gets toggled when the condition is encountered, and return true if the flag is toggled:

```js
function dropElements(arr, func) {
  let found = false;
  return arr.filter((item) => {
    if (found) return true;
    if (func(item)) {
      found = true;
      return true;
    }
  });
}

console.log(dropElements([1, 2, 3, 4], function(n) {
  return n > 5;
}));


console.log(dropElements([1, 2, 3, 4], function(n) {
  return n >= 3;
}))
```

I think `findIndex` followed by `slice` would be more appropriate, though:

```js
function dropElements(arr, func) {
  const startAtIndex = arr.findIndex(func);
  return startAtIndex === -1
    ? []
    : arr.slice(startAtIndex);
}

console.log(dropElements([1, 2, 3, 4], function(n) {
  return n > 5;
}));


console.log(dropElements([1, 2, 3, 4], function(n) {
  return n >= 3;
}))
```